# Chamar javascript passando variavel do php

Tags: php, javascript, java

Preciso chamar um javascript passando uma variável php para ele, quando coloco o script todo no php eu consigo passar a variavel dessa forma `location: '<?php echo $cidade;?>, BR'`,  mas quando chamo ele dessa forma `<script src="clima.js"></script>` não sei como informar a para o clima.js que a variável que ele deve usar é a $cidade que já existe no php

Comment: Queres passar a variável uma vez quando a página carrega ou queres passar dados depois da página carregar e sem recarregar a página?

Comment: Mais uma duplicata... O pessoal tinha que acostumar a olhar os relacionados ali do lado ou pesquisar se já tem resposta pra isso em vez de sair respondendo.

Comment: Concordo @Bacco, vamos criar uma discussão no Meta

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho que isso nem vem ao caso. Se o cara não le o relacionado, imagine participar do meta. Não vou dar -1 dessa vez nas respostas pq não tão "erradas" (e tem gente nova que tá ajudando na melhor intenção), apesar de ter umas feitas com bola de cristal.

Comment: @Sergio até cheguei a olhar e pesquisar em perguntas antigas mas não consegui entender como faria mesmo por isso resolvi postar uma nova pergunta acredito que esse possa ser um passo simples para programadores experientes e complicado para os novatos como pode ver eu fiz oque me foi sugerido e mesmo assim não funcionou caso possa dar uma ajuda será bem vinda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você definiu a variável `$cidade` na página PHP e quer referenciá-la diretamente (por meio de código PHP) no arquivo `clima.js`.

Se for este o caso não vai funcionar porque o bloco `<script src="clima.js"></script>` é interpretado pelo browser (cliente) e não pelo servidor (que é o caso dos códigos PHP).

O que você pode fazer para contornar isso é na página PHP inserir um código deste tipo:

```
<script src="clima.js"></script>
<?php
// este elemento HTML faz a separação entre os códigos server e client side
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cidade;?>" id='idCidade'/>

<script>
// obtenção do parâmetro cidade
var idCidade = window.document.getElementById ('idCidade').value;

// função do arquivo clima.js
var result=getClima(idCidade);
alert(result);
</script>
```

É uma boa prática a separação dos códigos server side e client side (no seu caso, PHP e Javascript respectivamente). Quanto mais separados, melhor para a manutenção e compreensão.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41381/discussion-on-answer-by-gwarah-chamar-javascript-passando-variavel-do-php)

Answer (score 1):

Bom eu lhe recomendaria atribuir a variável para um input e lá no javascript você  faz a captura do valor.

```
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $suavarial ?>" id='cidadeClima'/>

    <script>

     var getCidade = window.document.getElementById('cidadeClima').value;
     console.log(getCidade);

   </script>
```

Comment: +1 por não ter gambiarra.

Comment: Exceto pelo fato de estar usando `jQuery` e o mesmo não ter sido mencionado em nenhum momento.....

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, desculpa. Estão tão condicionado a usar jQuery, que quando penso (errado) em javaScript, já vem na cabeça o uso do jQuery. Mas vou editar a resposta para javascript

Comment: @CelsomTrindade alterado.

Comment: Como vai ser utilizado esse clima.js ? vai ficar visível em todas as páginas ou em uma página em especifico ?

Comment: @LucaoA o arquivo clima.js será chamado em varias páginas fiz da seguinte forma e funcionou veja se está da melhor forma no php ` <script>
  function varCod(){
   var cod = document.getElementById('idCidade').value;
   return cod;
  }
  var cCod = varCod();
 </script>` e no clima.js coloquei ` var cidade = cCod;

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $.simpleWeather({
  location: cidade+', BR',` funcionou está da forma correta

Comment: Se funcionou beleza. Só espero que não tenho dado um echo <script>...</script>, porque é totalmente contra a ideia de Designer Patterns.